# Dashboard escrow balance not updating when using Orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, balanced-payments

I'm processing a transaction using Orders in ruby because I wanted to consolidate the whole transaction while retaining all the extra "appears on statement" details. This extra refers to my recent pull request: https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby/pull/170

Everything shows up fine in the order's credit, debit and escrow field showing all calculations properly. The problem is that the escrow balance in the dashboard doesn't update.

Here is an example of the transaction:

```
order = merchant.create_order;
order.description = @description;
order.save;

debit = order.debit_from(
  :amount => amount,
  :appears_on_statement_as => @appears_as,
  :description => @description,
  :source => card
)

credit = order.credit_to(
  :destination => bank_account,
  :amount => payout,
  :appears_on_statement_as => @appears_as,
  :description => @description
)
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows why this works when debit/credit is done without orders but it fails to update when working with orders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each order maintains its own escrow amount, which is considered separate from the general marketplace escrow that you are referring to. Thus, the escrow balance for the marketplace will not update when orders are used.